# Drupal 7 and LDAP authentication with Active Directory

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, active-directory, ldap

I am using Drupal 7 ldap module (http://drupal.org/project/ldap) to authenticate with Windows Active Directory. I got the following error:

```
username : Beginning authentification....
username : Existing Drupal User Account not found. Continuing on to attempt ldap authentication
username : Trying server global_directory where bind_method = 2
username : Success at connecting to global_directory
ldap_search() call: base_dn: CN=Configuration,DC=ab,DC=cd,DC=ef, filter = (samaccountname=username), attributes: , attrsonly = 0, sizelimit = 0, timelimit = 0, deref = , scope = 3
username : Trying server global_directory where bind_method = 2. Error: Success
username : Authentication result id=0 auth_result=3 (Sorry, unrecognized username or password.)
username : Failed ldap authentication. User may have authenticated successfully by other means in a mixed authentication site. LDAP Authentication Error #: 3 error message: Sorry, unrecognized username or password.
Login attempt failed for username.
```

Settings:

```
sid = global_directory
numeric_sid = 1
name = Global Directory
status = 1
ldap_type = ad
address = ldaps://ldap.url
port = 3269
tls = 0
followrefs = 0
bind_method = 2
basedn = Array ( [0] => CN=Configuration,DC=ab,DC=cd,DC=ef )
binddn = 
user_dn_expression = %username@domain.com
user_attr = samaccountname
account_name_attr =
mail_attr = mail
mail_template =
picture_attr =
unique_persistent_attr =
unique_persistent_attr_binary = 0
ldap_to_drupal_user =
testing_drupal_username =
testing_drupal_user_dn =
grp_unused = 1
grp_object_cat =
grp_nested = 0
grp_user_memb_attr_exists = 0
grp_user_memb_attr =
grp_memb_attr =
grp_memb_attr_match_user_attr =
grp_derive_from_dn = 0
grp_derive_from_dn_attr =
grp_test_grp_dn =
grp_test_grp_dn_writeable =
search_pagination = 0
search_page_size = 1000
```

If I change BaseDNs to DC=cd,DC=ef
The error will be:

```
username : Beginning authentification....
username : Existing Drupal User Account not found. Continuing on to attempt ldap authentication
username : Trying server global_directory where bind_method = 2
username : Success at connecting to global_directory
ldap_search() call: base_dn: DC=cd,DC=ef, filter = (samaccountname=username), attributes: , attrsonly = 0, sizelimit = 0, timelimit = 0, deref = , scope = 3
ldap_search() function error. LDAP Error: Referral, ldap_search() parameters: ldap_search() call: base_dn: DC=cd,DC=ef, filter = (samaccountname=username), attributes: , attrsonly = 0, sizelimit = 0, timelimit = 0, deref = , scope = 3
username : Trying server global_directory where bind_method = 2. Error: Referral
username : Authentication result id=0 auth_result=8 (Authentication Server or Configuration Error.)
username : Failed ldap authentication. User may have authenticated successfully by other means in a mixed authentication site. LDAP Authentication Error #: 8 error message: Authentication Server or Configuration Error.
Login attempt failed for username.
```

Note: I use drupal ldap-7.x-2.0-beta5+24-dev

Anybody is facing the same problem? Any helps will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the baseDN apparently. on the first error, the authentication fails (login or password are wrong). As to the second one, there is some other problem in your configuration.

Have you checked everything? Enabled the ports in iptables? Because it seems to fail when it tries to contact with the server (bind_method; Authentication Server or Configuration Error).

I hope this helps at least to clarify the situation a little bit :)

Comment: Thanks @MPrazz, the problem now has been solved. The culprit was the ldap server security and port issue. I have to change the ldap address to: ldap.url (without: ldaps://) and port to 3268

Comment: @Borot, please mark the question as solved then :) And of course, accept an answer if it was useful :)

Comment: Actually, there is still an issue if I want to connect to ldap server through ssl with port 3269. The previous solution is somehow not a secured way to connect to AD and that is just a temporary solution. Should there be any issue with PHP ldap library or server certificate?

Comment: It is possible.. I would recommend giving a look at this website [tutorial](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tip/5838.html0). If you look around, they also have an article on how to test the ldap connection over ssl. Might help you find out what's wrong :)

Comment: Thanks @MPrazz, I have tried many possible ways with the Certificate file.. but it still doesn't work.

I finally found a magic: I have to write: _ldaps://ldap.url:3269_ in the Ldap Server field.

Answer (score 2):

I finally found a magic: 
I have to write: *ldaps://ldap.url:3269* in the LDAP server field and keep the same port number in LDAP port field.